# Failed to store data in the next loop of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know whats wrong with this code but whenever i would choose multiple forms to be filled up only the last part of the data will be displayed. For example i would choose 3 forms and fill it up with data only the last form is being stored. I used this code to display the data that is supposed to be in the array.

```
echo "<pre>";                                                
print_r($_POST);                                                         
echo "</pre>";
```

This is my code please help me

```
<?php

//  $_POST['countEmp'] is a variable from another page that would determine 
//  how many loops that it should execute  

$count = $_POST['countEmp'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM position";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$flag = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    echo " <form method='POST' action=insertProject1.php> ";
    echo " <input type='text' name='employee[]' placeholder='employee's name'> ";
    echo "<select  name='position[]'>";
    echo "<option selected='selected'>POSITION</option>";
       while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
           echo "<option value=".$data['position_id'].">".$data['position']."</option>";
        }   
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    $flag++;
    if ($flag== $count) {
        echo "<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='insert'>";
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($res,0);
    echo " </form> ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I wonder how do you submit all forms at the same time

Comment: `employee's` wants to be `employee\'s`  You don't need to bother writing ` selected='selected'` if you want the first option to be selected.  Why not pull the resultset down -- once -- save it to a variable and then loop the array, rather than making iterated calls of `while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {` and `mysqli_data_seek($res,0);`?

Comment: Do you need all three forms should be submitted?

Comment: Only single `<form>...</form>` is submitted at the time. If You need all of the inputs to be submitted, You have to put them all into single `<form>`, not into separate ones. Like this: `echo '<form...>'; for ($i...) { ... put the <input>s here ... } echo '</form>';`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have separate forms with their own submit buttons, the data submitted will only belong to clicked submit button's form.  You will need to restructure/consolidate your forms to generate your desired result.

Here's how I tested on my localhost:

```
<?php
var_export($_POST);
?>
<br>
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='employee[]' placeholder='employee&apos;s name'>
    <select  name='position[]'>
        <option>POSITION</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='insert1'>";
</form>
<br>
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='employee[]' placeholder='employee&apos;s name'>
    <select  name='position[]'>
        <option>POSITION</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='insert2'>";
</form>
<br>
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='employee[]' placeholder='employee&apos;s name'>
    <select  name='position[]'>
        <option>POSITION</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='insert3'>";
</form>
```

Along with the `employee[]` and `position[]` values, when I clicked the second submit button, I saw `$_POST['insert2'] = "SUBMIT"`.

---

If you want a structure like:

```
array (
    'employee' => array ( 0 => 'Frank', 1 => 'Jim', 2 => 'Earl', ),
    'position' => array ( 0 => '2', 1 => '1', 2 => '3', ),
    'insert' => 'SUBMIT',
)
```

Then wrap all of the fields in a single form with a single submit button.

---

Or if you want a structure like:

```
array (
   'set' => array (
       0 => array ( 'employee' => 'Candice', 'position' => '3', ),
       1 => array ( 'employee' => 'Bert', 'position' => '2', ),
       2 => array ( 'employee' => 'Abe', 'position' => '1', ),
   ),
   'insert' => 'SUBMIT',
)
```

Then you can build your single form something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='set[$i][employee]' placeholder='employee&apos;s name'>";
    echo "<select name='set[$i][position]'>";
        echo "<option>POSITION</option>";
        echo "<option value='1'>A</option>";
        echo "<option value='2'>B</option>";
        echo "<option value='3'>C</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='insert'>
</form>
```